# On passive voice

Tags: grammar

If I want to say, **I *am* told**, do I say, **Mir *werde* gesagt**?

And if I want to say, **I *was* told**, do I say, **Mir *wurde* gesagt**?

Similarly, if I want to say, **I *have been* told**, do I say, **Mir *bin* gesagt worden**?

And if I want to say, **I *had been* told**, do I say, **Mir *war* gesagt worden**?

Finally, if I want to say, **I *will* be told**, do I say, **Mir *werde* gesagt worden**?

And if I want to say, **I *will have been* told**, do I say, **Mir *werde* gesagt *worden sein***?

Comment: Your **werde**-forms are Konjunktiv I (indirect speech).

Comment: @Dario Can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/inflection/werden:V:sein

Comment: They're not; they are first person rather than third (which happen to be the same forms as Konjunktiv I 3rd person). Your mistake, @indoxica, is that you didn't notice that the direct object of "sagen" in German is NOT the person being told something, but the thing that is being said. The person (here: I, or mir) is the indirect object and hence dative. To come to the point: the syntactical subject in your passive voice sentence is the-thing-that's-being-said, so the finite verb "werden" needs to take third-person form. "Mir" is just a dative object.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness: You really just need to conjugate **werden** accordingly

> Mir **wird** gesagt
>
> Mir **wurde** gesagt
>
> Mir **ist** gesagt **worden**
>
> Mir **war** gesagt **worden**
>
> Mir **wird** gesagt **werden**
>
> Mir **wird** gesagt **worden sein**

Anyway, as pointed out you may want to replace passive voice with the less formal sounding impersonal **man**.

> Man **sagt** mir
>
> Man **sagte** mir
>
> ...
>
> Man **wird** mir **gesagt haben**

Now you conjugate **sagen** (note we need **haben** for perfect)

Comment: This is absolutely clear and perfectly comprehensible. Danke.

Comment: even though i would translate *i am told* as *man hört*, as it is idiomatic (correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: could you give a complete sentence as an example?

Comment: "Mir würde gesagt worden sein" fehlt noch :-P

Answer (score 2):

Some of them you got right, I would put them as follows:

```
Mir hat man gesagt
Mir wurde gesagt
Mir ist gesagt worden
Mir hatte man gesagt (Mir war gesagt worden)
Mir wird man sagen
Mir wird gesagt worden sein
```